# Create sequential variable names under SharedObject in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to create multi variables in a SharedObject with ActionScript 3.0, using the same name except with sequential numbers 1-100 behind?

Answer (score 1):

Besides dot notation you can access any object member with square brackets and the member name as a **String** variable. The following variants will equally invoke the **play()** method of the current **MovieClip**.

```
// Dot notation.
this.play();

// Square brackets.
var playName:String = "play";
this[playName]();
```

So it goes with any other object.

```
var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("my_shared_object");

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    SO.data["thing" + i] = Math.random();
}
```

**UPD**: As @Vesper pointed out, you can store a whole **Array** which lets you keep the indexed things naturally:

```
var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("my_shared_object");

SO.data.things = new Array;

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    SO.data.things[i] = Math.random();
}
```

Comment: Better yet, if you need many similar variables, then declare and use an array.